# Run multiprocess

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose, python-nose

I'm trying to run tests in parallel using nose.

I have setup a nose.cfg file to contain the following:

```
[nosetests]
verbosity=2
processes=2
```

I need to be able to run the programatically using either nose.main() or nose.run(). Whats the best way to do this? How do I select the test location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should invoke nose in Python code like this:

```
nose.run(defaultTest=test_location)
```

That'll run nose on tests beneath test_location (typically a directory).